# Java Pattern match from text file

Tags: java, string, text, replace

I have a file that I converted into a string it has several lines. I'm trying to just change the location of a directory which is the line

> Dir=C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\Temp

This path might be different between files and be of unknown length. 
It will always be

> Dir="something"\Temp.

I'm new any help is appreciated. I assume its the escaping of characters..but im not sure, I thought about using regular expressions but I think Ill run into the same issue.

Expected

> Dir=C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
>
> C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\
>
> Dir=\\\\LocalPC\\LocalTemp

Actual

> Dir=C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
>
> C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\
>
> Dir=C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp

```
public class test
{
    public String fileText;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     StartUpFile bob = new StartUpFile();

       System.out.println(bob.showFile());
       System.out.println(bob.temp());

       bob.change();
       System.out.println(bob.showFile());

    }
}

public class StartUpFile
{
    private String fileText;
    private String newText;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class StartUpFile
     */
    public StartUpFile()
    {
         newText = "\\\\"+"LocalPC";
         fileText = "Dir=C:"+"\\\\"+"Users"+"\\\\"+"admin"+"\\\\"+"AppData"+"\\\\"+"Local"+"\\\\"+"Temp";
    }
    /**
    * I want to ID the text bewtween "Dir=" and "Temp"
    */
    public String temp()
    {
      int startTemp = fileText.indexOf("Dir=") + 4;
      int EndTemp = fileText.indexOf("Temp");
      return fileText.substring(startTemp,EndTemp);
    }
    /**
    * show the string
    */ 
    public String showFile()
    {
        return fileText;
    }
    /**
     * swap the temp string for the newText
     */
    public void change()
    {
        fileText = fileText.replaceAll(temp(),newText);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up with using something like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has agreed with using regular expressions, So I sucked it up
They seam like something I should get good at.

I ended up with

```
String result = fileText.replaceAll("^*(?<==).*$", newText);
```

Which I read as starting on a line anything after = matching anything to the end of the line which works for my purpose. 
But if anyone knows how to state anything before "temp" I think it would be cleaner. Thank you. I think it was "Young Millie" that posted but then deleted his\her post

or it was "112g" I'm not sure.